# Read from serial port with timeout using boost

Tags: serial-port, boost-asio, access-violation

I want to write to a serial device. After each write I read from the device. I want to have a timeout for the read operation, if the device doesn't respond.

I've found a quite elegant solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456042/how-do-i-perform-a-nonblocking-read-using-asio). However, in my application, the port and the io_service are member variables, but when I try to instatiate the deadline_timer with the io_service member I get an access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem creating a deadline_timer with an io_service that is a member variable.

If the deadline_timer is a member in the same class as the io_service, you must make sure that the deadline_timer is declared after the io_service so that the io_service has been constructed when the time comes to construct the deadline_timer.

Comment: Construction in the correct order did solve this problem, but the next access violation occurred, when calling async_read() with bind()

Comment: 2nd access violation was caused, because io_service was not the first member variable.