# What is the difference of boost asio serial_port_service and serial_port

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I am to implement a (hopefully) robust asynchronious serial rs232 data transmission (via USB) - for both windows and linux, including esp. that nice embedded system called  beagle bone black.

In the end I just want to be able to (compatibly) talk rs232 with robust deadline-timeouts, cancel() reset() etc. to not crash/hang when e.g. the tx or rx line disconnects accidently. So sure, I could simply copy/paste/adopt existing examples. But I also would like to become more enlightened ;-)

I decided to use [boost:asio::serial_port](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html). Now while reading the docs, I am confused about this two classes (well three with the typedef serial_port):

[serial_port_service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_service.html) - Default service implementation for a serial port.

```
class serial_port_service : public io_service::service
```

[basic_serial_port](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port.html) - Provides serial port functionality.

```
template< typename SerialPortService = serial_port_service>
class basic_serial_port :
  public basic_io_object< SerialPortService >,
  public serial_port_base
```

So faar I see, that I need a `boost::asio::io_service` to construct either `boost::asio::serial_port` or `serial_port_service`.
I think I have understand the basic approach how asio does the job, like bespoken in e.g. [this examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551617/reading-a-serial-port-asynchronously-boost?rq=1) .

OK `serial_port_service` derives from io_service, its ctor takes an `io_service`, and its interface also offers those memberfuncs of `basic_serial_port`.

For me it looks like it's a io_service that also implements a basic_serial_port - what is the reason for having *both* classes? When to use the one when the other? Not sure about possible usecases, and what about this `serial_port` typedef. Maybe (well obviously) I am missing something - someone can give me more light?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often, the application should use the I/O object.  In this case, that would be [`boost::asio::serial_port`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html).

---

The various classes are used to separate responsibilities and abstractions.  The similarity in names can be confusing, so the documentation is very careful in its naming.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.the_io_service_class_and_i_o_services) states:

> Class `io_service` implements an extensible, type-safe, polymorphic set of I/O services, indexed by service type. An object of class `io_service` must be initialised before I/O objects such as sockets, resolvers and timers can be used. These I/O objects are distinguished by having constructors that accept an `io_service&` parameter.
>
> I/O services exist to manage the logical interface to the operating system on behalf of the I/O objects. In particular, there are resources that are shared across a class of I/O objects. For example, timers may be implemented in terms of a single timer queue. The I/O services manage these shared resources.

To explain this in context of serial ports:

- The [`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) provides an event processing loop and manages I/O services, such as [`serial_port_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_service.html).
- The [`serial_port`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html) is an I/O object that provides an interface to perform serial port related operations.  The implementation is very basic:

  - Determines how information is to be returned to the caller: throw if an error occurs, populate a [`std::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html), suspend a [coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html), etc.
  - Defers the actual work to the `serial_port_service`, its I/O service.
  - Provides [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) semantics.  When the `serial_port` is destroyed, it will cancel outstanding asynchronous operations and close the `serial_port`.
- The `serial_port_service` is an I/O service:

  - It provides an abstraction and implements the platform specific API.
  - It is shared amongst `serial_port`s that use the same `io_service`.  When the `serial_port` is created with an `io_service`, the `serial_port` will use an existing `serial_port_service` registered to the `io_service` or create and register a new `serial_port_service` with the `io_service`.
  - It functions as an factory for an I/O object's [`implementation`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/get_implementation.html).  For a `serial_port`, this is likely a basic file descriptor or handle.

Comment: Hm.. so serial_ports sharing the same io_service also share the same serial_port_service. One cancel() will also cancel all other serial_ports of that io_service then, right?

So when I want to read/write to different ports (e.g. com3 com4) I use different io_services in serial_port ctors - otherwise they would interfere from each other?
I would do something like:
serial_port serial1(io_stream1);
serial1.open("com3", ec); 
serial_port serial2(io_stream2);
serial2.open("com4", ec); 
Then serial2.cancel() would not cancel serial1?

Comment: When doing async_read_some - is there any chance to use a deadline-timer which cancelS *only* the overdue read operation it is related - I mean without canceling also the ongoing write operations?
Until now I only found serial_port.cancel()  - and no way to cancel individual async_read_some operations...

Comment: @tverrbjelke Calling `cancel()` on an I/O object will cancel all outstanding operations on that distinct I/O object and should have no observable affect on any other I/O object, even those that use the same `io_service` and  I/O service.

Comment: So do I correctly understand you? When I have opened two serial ports s1(Com3) and s2(com4) with different io_services. Then a async_read_some timeout handler does s1.cancel() it would cancel all ongoing read *and* write operations on com3, but it would not bother com4. 

Is there any way to let an related timeout handler watching async_read_some() kill only it's (s1) *read* operations? Without also killing any parallel async_write_some() operations on s1? How to asynchroniously check for "data ready to be read" without deadline_timer canceling everything?

Comment: @tverrbjelke The statements are correct, but I want to stress that canceling a distinct I/O object (`s1`) will have no affect on another distinct I/O object (`s2`), regardless of which `io_service` they use.  There is no way to cancel a specific type of operations on an I/O object.  To be asynchronously informed of when data is ready without actually reading it, try using [reactor-style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) operations.  Also, the `async_write_some()` handler could initiate another `async_write_some()` operation if canceled.